# The service cannot find the resource identified by the resource URI and selectors

Tags: command-line, windows-server-2012, syntax

When run `winrm set -?` command, I can see the following example how to disable a listener:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>winrm set -?
Windows Remote Management Command Line Tool

winrm set RESOURCE_URI [-SWITCH:VALUE [-SWITCH:VALUE] ...]
          [@{KEY="VALUE"[;KEY="VALUE"]}]
          [-file:VALUE]

Modifies settings in RESOURCE_URI using specified switches
and input of changed values via key-value pairs or updated
object via an input file.

Example: Disable a listener on this machine:
  winrm set winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS @{Enabled="false"}
```

However, when I run exactly the same command in `cmd` as suggested above, I've got the error:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>winrm set winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS @{Enabled="false"}
WSManFault
    Message
        ProviderFault
            WSManFault
                Message = The WS-Management service cannot process the request. The service cannot find the resource identified by the resource URI and selectors.

Error number:  -2144108544 0x80338000
The WS-Management service cannot process the request. The service cannot find the resource identified by the resource URI and selectors.
```

And in PS I've got different error:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> winrm set winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS @{Enabled="false"}
Error: Invalid use of command line. Type "winrm -?" for help.
```

The service is up and running (`test-wsman` in PS runs fine):

```
C:\Users\Administrator>winrm e winrm/config/Listener
Listener
    Address = *
    Transport = HTTP
    Port = 5985
    Hostname
    Enabled = true
    URLPrefix = wsman
    CertificateThumbprint
    ListeningOn = 10.152.26.30, 127.0.0.1, ::1,fe80::5efe:10.152.26.30%14, fe80::f9c5:141f:ff25:6253%12
```

What am I missing? How can I run the above example successfully?

Answer (score 0):

The command failed, because `Transport` is set to `HTTP`, not `HTTPS`, that's why selector `Transport=HTTPS` failed to find the existing resource.

So the command should be:

```
winrm set winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTP @{Enabled="false"}
```

The command should be executed in a Command Prompt ([`cmd.exe`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe)) as it fails in PS.